# Does "a" in "I made a mistake" denote indefiniteness?

Tags: terminology, determiners, indefinite-article

> I made a mistake.

Here, "a" is called the **indefinite** article in contrast with the **definite** article "the".

But does "a" in this sentence denote indefiniteness?

As far as I can tell, "a" is needed here not because we need to make *mistake* indefinite but because we need to make it an individual, separate entity.

I can prove the above argument as follows.

Once "a" is removed from the above sentence, it becomes ungrammatical as follows:

> *I made mistake.

Now, is this sentence ungrammatical because now *mistake* isn't indefinite anymore without "a"?

Or because now *mistake* isn't an individual, separate entity anymore without "a"?

If this proves that *a* in *I made a mistake* doesn't denote indefiniteness, why do we have to call it the indefinite article?

Comment: How do you define indefiniteness?

Comment: @WavesWashSands Indefiniteness is lack of definiteness.

Comment: "I made two mistakes" is grammatically "indefinite," contrasted to "I made *the* two mistakes"

Comment: @ba You're right. But it's not _two_ that makes it "indefinite". And it's not _a_ or _one_ that makes _I made a/one mistake_ indefinite either.

Comment: It is an article, and it is used in contradistinction to the **definite** article. Next question?

Comment: I don’t know why you’re focusing on count or number when analyzing definiteness. Definiteness is determined by specificity. There’s “a star”, which is indefinite because there are a gazillion stars and we don’t know which one we’re talking about, and “the sun” because now we do: it’s *the* star the Earth orbits. It’s *defined*, identified. The indefinite comes from the fact that you could replace it with *any* (because within that class, the individuals are indistinguishable); that makes it easy to see number doesn’t matter *any star*, *any two stars*.

Comment: @JK2: But how do you define definiteness...?

Comment: You're over-thinking this. "a(n)" is an article, I hope we can agree on that. So, what kind of article is it? Well, it's not a definite article. So, we can call it a not-definite article, i.e., an *indefinite article*.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I'm afraid all the linguists who came up with this term 'indefinite article' were all underthinking this. Rather than come up with a term in its own right, they chose to make up a term simply based on "a/an" being not the definite article. And because of the laziness on the part of those linguists, a whole lot of unnecessary confusion arises.

Comment: I first disagree that “indefinite” does not capture the semantics of the article, and second disagree that there’s any kind of confusion created by the term. The only time I’ve seen anyone express uncertainty about it is literally right here in this question.

Comment: If you have a *question* "Why do you call “a/an” the indefinite article?", then it can be answered. If you instead have an "argument against calling "a/an" the indefinite article", that is a debate or opinion with no answer and is not suitable for this site.

Comment: @DanBron If the same question has come up before, my question would be closed as being a duplicate, wouldn't it? Then, why it being raised as a question for the first time for one person (i.e., you) should be any problem, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @MarkBeadles My question is as the title says. The "argument against" part is only added in an effort to show how absurd this well-known term can be.

Comment: @JK2 I don’t understand your most recent comment. What I’m saying is I have not ever seen this question before you asked, which is evidence that the confusion you report is not widespread, and possibly confined to just you. I don’t see anything incorrect or ambiguous about the “indefinite” in “indefinite article”, and I haven’t seen anyone else complain about it before you. I think this is an invented (ie non-existent) issue.

Comment: @DanBron Then, please go ahead and write your own answer by addressing the same examples I have used in my question. I think that would be a piece of cake for you since you think this is not an issue.

Comment: @DanBron I'll make this easier for you. If you can convince me that _a_ in _I made a mistake_ denotes indefiniteness rather than individuation, that's all I need as the perfect answer.

Comment: Based on your examples, I think you're [confusing definiteness and specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(linguistics)#Relationship_Between_Specificity_and_Definiteness).

Comment: *Etymologically, "a/an" means "one"* That's not how etymology works. Etymologically, "a/an" *comes from* "one", but it does not determine what it means now. Etymology informs our understanding but is no substitute for actually investigating the meaning of words [synchronically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrony_and_diachrony).

Comment: @JK2 I already answered you, in my first comment in this thread. So far as I see it, nothing else needs to be said. Your most recent comments read to me along the lines of “if you can prove to me that cows don’t have purple polka dots, that would be enough”. It seems more to me that you the onus is on you to demonstrate there’s an issue with the nomenclature than for others to demonstrate there isn’t.

Comment: @curiousdannii Since I'm dumb enough to have no clue what you mean by your comments full of more confusing terms when I am actually confused about one of the most fundamental grammar terms of all time, please write your own answer directly addressing my question using my examples. Like I said in an earlier comment to someone else, if you can convince me that _a_ in _I made a mistake_ denotes indefiniteness rather than individuation, that's all I need as the perfect answer.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles are simple enough. If you ever decide to answer WavesWashSands's questions then we might be able to give a more helpful explanation, but without understanding how you understand these terms, there's little I can do that would be more helpful than to say go read the articles: "definiteness ... distinguish[es] between referents/entities that are **identifiable** in a given context ... and entities which are not" / "specificity ... distinguishes between entities/nouns/referents that are **unique** in a given context and those that are not"

Comment: @DanBron I take it that you cannot explain why _a_ in _I made a mistake_ does not denote indefiniteness. By the way, your first comment on "star" "Earth", etc isn't helping at all. Why do you have to come up with a different example that has got nothing to do with my question? Can I say _I made any mistake_?? What does that tell me about my question?

Comment: @JK2 You take it wrong. But that’s not my issue. And you can say “I made some mistake”.

Comment: @DanBron No. I know you know you can't explain what I've asked you to explain. So, simply saying that I take it wrong won't do anything for me...or for you. So I guess it's your issue. In case you didn't read my question carefully, _I made some mistake_ is one of the example sentences I have in my question.

Comment: You are wrong again.  It is your attitude and your obstinance which dissuades me from explaining; you didn't even bother to engage with my first comment until I pointed it out again. So I'm not interesting in doing anything more for you. And don't worry about me doing things for me; I've got a handle on that.

Comment: I had written an answer which addressed your original question "Why do you call "a/an" the indefinite article?". Unfortunately, now that you have changed your question, my answer no longer applies and I have deleted it.

Comment: @DanBron I didn't "engage with your first comment", not because I didn't want to bother or I was lazy, but because your first comment talks about apples when I asked about oranges. You could have written up a nice answer to my question with half the effort you put in writing these useless comments, but you didn't. So please don't blame it on MY attitude.

Comment: @JK2 Please never accuse any specific individuals of downvoting posts. Votes are anonymous for good reasons.

Comment: @JK2 I didn't downvote you. But if you continue to insult me, I'll be tempted.

Comment: @curiousdannii "Accuse"? What's wrong with giving a downvote? Is it an illegal activity? No! So, please don't say I "accused" anyone of anything.

Comment: @JK2 "@DanBron And thanks for the -1" That's an accusation, and one you have no evidence for.

Comment: @curiousdannii It’s also one it’s impossible for him to have evidence for, because I haven’t downvoted him.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's called "guessing", not "accusation". And I'm entitled to my own little guessing just as you are entitled to your own little downvoting.

Comment: @JK2 If you're guessing, be explicit. But really, keep your guessing to yourself. No one wants to read about your guesses. (Or anyone else's. That's faux pas number one on Stack Exchange.)

Answer (score 3):

> Once "a" is removed from the above sentence, it becomes ungrammatical as follows:
>
> > *I made mistake.
>
> Now, is this sentence ungrammatical because now mistake isn't indefinite anymore without "a"?

No, your example sentence is ungrammatical in English because the rules of English require that all singular countable nouns have some sort of [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner).

---

> As far as I can tell, "a" is needed here not because we need to make mistake indefinite but because we need to make it an individual, separate entity.

"Individual, separate entity": this sounds like the semantic category of ["specificify"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(linguistics)).

By contrast, the semantic category of ["definiteness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness) concerns **identifiability**. You use definite markers when you think your listeners can identify the referents of your noun phrases, and you use indefinite markers when you think your listeners would not be able to identify the referents.

When you say "I made a mistake", you know what the mistake is, but your listeners do not because this is the first time that they've heard about it. If you go on to explain what the mistake is, then it becomes appropriate to say "the mistake" because your listeners can now identify what you're talking about.

Wikipedia [gives a few helpful examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(linguistics)#Relationship_Between_Specificity_and_Definiteness) which show that the English articles, when they are present, do indeed mark definiteness (identifiability), *not specificity*.

> *I'm looking for **the manager**, Ms Lee.* [definite, specific]
> *I'm looking for **the manager**, whoever that may be.* [definite, non-specific]
> *There's **a certain word** that I can never remember.* [indefinite, specific]
> *Think of **a word**, any word.* [indefinite, non-specific]

Comment: Thanks. But even if the listener knows what the mistake is, should the speaker say "I made the mistake"? I think I'd most likely say "I made a mistake" even my listener knows what the mistake is. So, it's less reason for us to call "a" the indefinite article, I think.

Comment: @JK2 There are probably social factors with the word "mistake" where even if everyone knows about the mistake, they pretend not to so that the mistake maker can save face. For most nouns, if the speaker believes the listener knows what they're talking about it would be wrong and confusing to say "a".

Comment: The famous syntax to save face in the wake of mistakes is ***[mistakes were made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistakes_were_made)***. And no, in real pragmatics, once the mistake is identified, people would talk about "the mistake", as in "someone unplugged the mainframe" / "who made the mistake?".

Comment: @curiousdannii I've been thinking about this. How could a mistake maker possibly "save face" by saying "a mistake" instead of "the mistake" when they're already admitting to the fact that they made "a" mistake?? Moreover, even when you say something opposite to "mistake", you tend to use "a" even when the listener already knows about it. For example, when you praise someone for their work that they already know about, you say, "You did a great job", not "You did the great job".

Comment: @DanBron In your 'mainframe' example, let's say, everybody already knows that someone unplugged the mainframe. Now, the one who accidentally did it can easily say "I made a mistake" instead of "I made the mistake". Moreover, in your "mistakes were made" example, the "saving face" factor lies not in "mistakes" being without "the", but in the sentence being in the passive voice.

Comment: @JK2 The listener allows the speaker to save face by pretending they don't know about the mistake so that the speaker can explain what they've done in their own way at their own time. Why we say "you did a great job" would be a good thing to ask, as another question, probably at ELU.

Comment: @curiousdannii I respectfully disagree. It's not about the listener allowing the speaker to save face. "I made a mistake" is what the speaker, not the listener, feels a natural thing to say. And it's a very unfortunate thing for you not to directly address the "a great job" example by saying I should go to **a** different site ("ELU") to ask **the** same question. Now, why did I use "a" to refer to ELU (something you already mentioned) and "the" for "question"?

Answer (score 2):

The "indefinite article" is called that because it is an article* and it is used with indefinite noun phrases. It certainly isn't a necessary part of all indefinite noun phrases: the English indefinite article is specifially a singular article, unlike the definite article, so it isn't used with plural or non-count nouns.

As you've noted, not all indefinite noun phrases have "a/an", so in most contexts the presence of the indefinite article doesn't exactly mark indefiniteness. Rather, in many contexts indefiniteness in English is indicated mainly by the absence of the definite article. The presence of the indefinite article with an indefinite common noun indicates that the noun phrase is grammatically singular and count. When the indefinite article is absent, a noun phrase is usually interpreted as plural or indefininte noncount (e.g. the difference between "a stone" and "stones" or "stone"); if that interpretation is impossible, the noun phrase will just seem to be ungrammatical (as in your example "*I made mistake").

The indefinite article does serve as a marker of indefiniteness when it appears before proper nouns that usually lack a definite article even when they are definite, like people's given names. A noun phrase like "Sandy" is definite; a noun phrase like "a Sandy" is indefinite.

### *The definition of "article"

The definition of the word "article" seems to be somewhat unclear. Its application to "a/an" is traditional, not necessarily based on any deep underlying connection between this word and "the" (although they do have similarities; they are both determiners).

For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) says that "The articles in English grammar are *the* and *a/an,* and in certain contexts *some*", whereas [another source](https://ctlgsp.wikispaces.com/file/view/articles.def.indef.pdf) refers to *some* as an "article equivalent". Obviously, these are not particularly advanced linguistic sources; I just am trying to make the point that at least some people seem to be confused about, or disagree about, what exactly the word "article" refers to. So you shouldn't necessarily expect the terminology in this area to have much explanatory value.

A point similar to the one that you seem to be making was made in "[On the Article in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=7mBbDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=linguistics%20definition%20indefinite%20article&source=bl&ots=h9uTjpUXDc&sig=jDh2ICcSmB3mkKq_-nIfuBQTPrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0kun1_pPYAhWL5oMKHcFqBkw4ChDoAQg_MAQ#v=onepage&q=linguistics%20definition%20indefinite%20article&f=false)", by David M. Perlmutter, in 1970.  Perlmutter says that

> If this is correct, the relationship between the definite article and the indefinite article in English is quite different from what has been generally supposed. Grammarians have worked on the assumption that NP's may bear either a definite or an indefinite article, and that the two constitute some sort of opposition. If the analysis given here is correct, however, the indefinite article is simply a numeral like all other numerals, and the occurence or non-occurence of the definite article is a completely independent phenomenon.

I don't know how Perlmutter's paper was received (some parts of the analysis seem a bit far-fetched to me), and I don't know what kind of progress has been made on the characterization of the indefinite article since then; I know that I've seen other analyses that treat the indefinite article as some kind of special reduced version of the numeral "one" (which is consistent with the etymology, although that doesn't prove that it's a correct synchronic analysis).

Comment: Thanks. Then, shouldn't "a" be called "the singular article" rather than "the indefinite article"?

Comment: JK2: the referents of *the* is also singular. "The star" (one star), "a star" (one star). And yes, works the same way for "mistake".

Comment: @JK2 Is "a few oranges" singular?

Comment: @JK2: "a" is a singular indefinite article.

Comment: @DanBron Good point! But "a" in "I made a mistake" doesn't denote indefiniteness, but you still call "a" the indefinite article. Moreover, the core meaning of "the" in "the star" is not that "star" is singular, but that "star" is definite, and that "star" happens to be singular by chance. That's why you can also say "the stars".

Comment: JK2: Yes, your observation about "the stars" is true *it has nothing to do with number*, it has to do with *definiteness*.  We *know* which star or starts, or mistake or mistakes: we are *definite* about them. When we are *not* definite about them, we use the *indefinite* article.

Comment: @DanBron I think your last comment is perfect except your last sentence needs revising as follows: When we are not definite about them, we use the indefinite article only if we talk about an individual, separate entity.

Comment: Nope.  A few clams.  That's not an individual, separate entity.

Comment: @sumelic Right. "Singular indefinite article" might be the term I was looking for!

Comment: @DanBron I think "a" in "a few clams" still denotes an individual, separate entity, because "few clams" as a whole is considered as an individual, separate entity.

Comment: There's no way to argue "few clams" is considered a "individual separate entity". No one has an image in their heads of "few clams" as a individual, separate entity. You might be arguing that "a few" is *grammatically* singular, as in takes singular agreement, but the terminology "definite" and "indefinite" arise from the *semantics*, not syntax, of the referent, and this whole conversation has revolved around the *meaning* of these articles. No, there's no way to make an argument that "a" is "the singular article". The debate bottoms out where it started: *a* is **indefinite**.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think "a few" is grammatically singular or is treated as singular. I'm not saying that "few clams" in and of itself is an individual, separate entity. It clearly is in a plural form. What I'm saying is that "a" lumps otherwise plural "few clams" together into a single package, if you will. But the single package is still considered plural _grammatically_ because what "a few clams" refers to _semantically_ is "a plurality of clams".

Comment: @DanBron Alternatively, "a few" as a whole is considered as a determinative. So, "a" in "a few clams" does not directly determine "clams", but only combines with "few" to form a determinative in its own right: "a few", which subsequently determines "clams". The same is the case with "a little" in "a little money", where "a" doesn't determine "money" directly, cause "money" is uncountable. Instead, "a" combines with "little" to form a different determinative "a little", which then determines "money".

Comment: @DanBron All in all, I don't find it convincing using "a few clams" as evidence against limiting the use of the indefinite article to an individual, separate entity.